# i have issue in Multi-select in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I need to create a shiny app with two select 1 inputs and one output, where if I select A in the first select, the second select should show "A1", "A2." I did that, but when I try to download A1, I get an empty CVS. i know that I have issue in the datasetInput
Can anyone assist me in resolving this issue?

my cod is:-

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(readxl)

# set working directory to this script's locations: no need to check the file path manually
setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))

A1 <- read_excel("A1.xlsx")
A2 <- read_excel("A2.xlsx")
B1 <- read_excel("B1.xlsx")
B2 <- read_excel("B2.xlsx")
C1 <- read_excel("C1.xlsx")
C2 <- read_excel("C2.xlsx")

#ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Flood"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      # Input: Choose dataset ----
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:",
                  choices = c("A", "B", "C")),
      
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
     uiOutput("secondSelection"))))
 

# Define server logic to display and download selected file ----
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
 
  # Table of selected dataset ----
   output$secondSelection <- renderUI({
   selectInput( "file",  "Choose a file:", choices = 
      switch(input$dataset,
             "A" = c("A1","A2") ,
             "B" = c("B1","B2"),
             "C" = c("C1","C2"))
  )
  })
  
   
  # Reactive value for selected dataset ----
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(file,
           "A1" = A1,
           "A2" = A2,
           "B1" = B1,
           "B2" = B2,
           "C1" = C1,
           "C2" = C2)
  }) 
  
  
  # Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste(input$dataset, ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(datasetInput(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
}

# Create Shiny app ----
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Where is "A1" or "A2" defined?

Comment: they are defined in the header, but I didn't add the header

Comment: I guess you need `input$file` in `datasetInput`

Comment: Oh, thank you so much; it works for me now; I was confused since I didn't notice that xD.